# 1 computer, 2 programs, 2 NICs on 2 different subnets, open socket/bind port conflicts between the two programs, why?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, port, bind

I am working on a project with C/C++ on Linux, and need to connect to two similar network devices using an API that I know just a little about.

The organization I have is 1 computer, and two ethernet adapters.

Let's call it lan1 adapter, is set to IP: 100.1.1.2 and the network device target is 100.1.1.1, with subnet 255.255.255.0.

lan2 adapter has IP: 100.1.2.2 and the network device target is 100.1.2.1, also with subnet 255.255.255.0

I am building two separate programs that each use the same net initialization code to connect to the network targets.

The problem is that after the first program initializes its connection to its respective network target, the other program fails to bind its port when it tries to initialize its own network connection to its respective target. I am not sure why this conflict between programs exists, seeing as how everything should be separate.

Below is the portion of the API that attempts to create a socket and bind a port:

```
static short create_socket(int port, UINT32 blocking)
{
    int trycount =0;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    int r;
    u_long yes = blocking ? 0 : 1;      // nonblocking toggle
    BOOL en = TRUE;

    if ((our_socket= socket(PF_INET/*AF_INET*/, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) <0)
    {
        printf("Socket open failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    if(!yes)
        r = 0; // by default it is blocking
    else
        r= fcntl(our_socket,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
    if(r<0)
    {
         printf("IOCTL failed setting blocking state: %d %d ", r, errno);
         closesocket(our_socket);
         return r;
    }



    bzero((char *) &sin, sizeof(sin));
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sin.sin_port =  htons((unsigned short)port);

    r = bind(our_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));
    while(r == EADDRINUSE && trycount <10  )
    {
            port ++;
            sin.sin_port =  htons((unsigned short)port);
            r = bind(our_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));
            trycount ++;
    }
    if(r<0)
    {
        printf("Socket BIND failed: %d %d port %d\n", r, errno, port);
        closesocket(our_socket);
        return r;
    }

    r = setsockopt( our_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (const char *)&en, sizeof(en));
    if(r)
    {
      printf("Socket Broadcast enable failed: %d\n", r);
      closesocket(our_socket);
      return r;
    }
        recvcount = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

By default the blocking is enabled by the input argument, and the error throws the message "Socket BIND failed".

I have also tried disabling blocking, and instead get another error that socket file descriptor is marked as O_NONBLOCK and one of the operations (haven't figure out which yet) would cause it to block. Although, I'm not even sure the 'blocking' is the reason for the conflict between the two programs.

Any idea why the two separate programs conflict at this point in initializing the network connection to their respective targets, and how it might be avoided?

Thanks,
B

Comment: It is easy to tell if you let two process to bind the same port, you failed binding. your code suggests that.

Comment: Thanks @EOF for that direction, some research this says that "INADDR_ANY is used when you don't need to bind a socket to a specific IP" and "When INADDR_ANY is specified in the bind call, the socket will be bound to all local interfaces." I'm not sure that lulyon read my post thoroughly, and that I was using separate interfaces, because the reason for the failure to bind wasn't that clear, and binding a specific port shouldn't be so general, unless I guess that INADDR_ANY parameter is used as it is in my code. Want to answer the question, and I'll accept?

Answer (score -1):

As per @EOF, the problem was

```
INADDR_ANY
```

in the line

```
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

which caused the port to be bound on all available network interfaces.

Edit: fixed a bad copy/paste problem

Comment: It was in the line after that actually.

Comment: @EJP, you're right, I fixed it now. Chalked up to a bad copy/paste selection on my phone. If you down voted my answer because of that, please change the vote accordingly.